# How can import my Tynker projects to Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

My cousin told me that I can put my Tynker projects on my Nintendo Switch but hasn't told me how, and I tried everything, nothing worked. Google is telling me the wrong console type and I really need some help on how to do it.

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to import? A mod? A texture pack?

Comment: mods and skins.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't possible without a PC or mobile device.

The only way to get addons or resource packs on the Nintendo Switch is to purchase a Minecraft Realm, Import the packs onto the Realm's world via a PC or Mobile device, then download the Realms world on your Nintendo. You can only play with those packs on that single world. Also custom skins are not supported by the console.